# C++ WINAPI Exception Unhandled Stack Overflow before reaching code

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, directx, stack-overflow

I've put together a nice little terrain engine in direct x. I changed the `width` and `height` of the land from `256` to `512` and now when I run the debugger the program crashes in `wWinMain`. The `Width` and `Height` are `const static unsigned int`
I should add that if I change the numbers back to 256 the program debugs fine without error. Only when changing these numbers does it throw a stack-overflow error.

*`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF7065C9FB8 in TerrainEngine.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000022AA803000).`*

```
class Constants
{
public:
    // World rows and columns
    const static unsigned int WorldWidth = 256; //changing this to a number greater than
    const static unsigned int WorldHeight = 256; //256 causes stack overflow
```

When changing WorldWidth or WorldHeight to a number greater than 256 I get a stack overflow error at the very beginning of my code, so early that I'm unable to properly debug further to see what's going wrong.

[image]

```
void World::Initialize(Graphics & graphics)
{
    this->graphics = &graphics;

    ....

    // Setup Perlin Noise
    PerlinNoise perlinNoise = PerlinNoise(237);

    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < Constants::WorldHeight; y++)
    {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < Constants::WorldWidth; x++)
        {
            double xx = (double)x / ((double)Constants::WorldWidth);
            double yy = (double)y / ((double)Constants::WorldHeight);

            //define in header as std::array<std::array<float, Constants::WorldWidth>, Constants::WorldHeight> heightmap;
            heightmap[x][y] = perlinNoise.noise(xx, yy, 1);
            tileManager.SetTile(x, y, Math::GetType(heightmap[x][y]));
        }
    }
}


void World::Update(Keyboard& keyboard)
{
    // The only other time WorldWidth is referenced
    //posX is public signed int
    posX = Math::Clamp(
        posX,
        Constants::WorldWidth - Constants::RenderWidth,
        Constants::RenderWidth);
```

Can anyone explain what's happening, cause I'm unable to debug past the first curly brace which leads to the wWinMain method, and I don't understand how changing these two values can cause the program to throw this error.

World is declared as raw, ordinary private member in the Game header file.

```
World world;
```

It has one constructor that is empty.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: I'm unable to debug it while the values are greater than 256 else the compiler doesn't get that far. Else nothing seems out of the ordinary. I know the constructor that takes the width and height and uses them to declare a pointer-to-pointer array.

Comment: Does `std::cout << sizeof( MainWindow ) << sizeof( Game ) << "\n";` tell you anything? If it doesn't run as-is, you can comment out the two `try` blocks.

Comment: What's the stack trace when you get the failure?  Probably you have infinite recursion in a global variable initialization.

Comment: Where is the [mcve]? Or is your question a request for a tutorial in debugging?

Comment: You haven't shown the code where `width` and `height` are used.  You already know that changing those produces your problem, so why are you not looking at that code?

Comment: @BenVoigt Right-o, I've added all instances of Width and Height being referenced in my original post.

Comment: Show the code where `World` instance is created. If you created it onto stack you have problem, stack's size is limited, default value on windows is 1MB, so `512*512*sizeof(float)` gives you 1 MB. Hence stack overflow. Create `World` onto heap, by `new`.

Comment: I've now added in my original post how World is created, but to summarise here it's just declared in Game.h as a regular member. What you're describing about the size being limited, that sounds like my problem. Cheers @rafix07

Comment: I'm fairly sure you have a `double heightmap[Constants::WorldWidth][Constants::WorldHeight]` you forgot to tell us about.  That array will be too big to fit in the stack.  Replace it with `std::unique_ptr<double [][WorldHeight]> heightmap = std::make_unique<double [][WorldHeight]>(WorldWidth);`

Comment: Edit: Ah! Thank you!

Comment: @Anthony: nested `std::array` is still an in-place allocation, so it won't solve your problem.  In addition, it's only *almost* contiguous, not exactly the same as a 2-D array.  Your 2-D new is what you want, but it needs a corresponding `delete[]` somewhere, which is taken care of by the modern smart pointer equivalent I'm suggesting.

Comment: Okey-dokey, I've changed the heightmap in the header file from nested std::arrays to `std::unique_ptr<float[][Constants::WorldHeight]> heightmap;` as you suggested, and defined it in the constructor like `World::World() {heightmap = std::make_unique<float[][Constants::WorldHeight]>(Constants::WorldWidth); }` but I'm still getting the error so I'm guessing I've declared it wrong. Working though, am able to increase the width and height to 475

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very large array which presently is part of a variable with automatic lifetime that the compiler places on the stack.  Since it's too big to fit, you get a stack overflow.

Replace your array declared as

```
double heightmap[Constants::WorldWidth][Constants::WorldHeight];
```

by

```
std::unique_ptr<double [][Constants::WorldHeight]> heightmap{std::make_unique<double [][Constants::WorldHeight]>(Constants::WorldWidth)};
```

You will also have to `#include <memory>` if you haven't already.

Nothing else needs to change<sup>1</sup>.  `make_unique` will allocate the storage for the same exact contiguous 2-D array you had before, only it will be dynamically allocated instead of taking up stack space.  And `unique_ptr` is smart enough to automatically free the storage when the class instance that owns it goes away.

---

<sup>1</sup> Only probably true.  `std::unique_ptr<Type[]>` supports subscripting with `[]`, so your current code `heightmap[x][y]` will continue working.  If you used array-to-pointer decay anywhere without subscripting, you will now need `heightmap.get()` or `&heightmap[0][0]` instead of just the bare array name.

Comment: Thanks Ben for all your help